# .bashrc in the cloud?

Tags: bash, synchronization

I do alot of development from the terminal at both work and home.  What's a good solution for keeping all of my .bashrc, .vimrc, .screenrc, Irssi configs and scripts, etc. in sync across multiple machines?

I was thinking of setting up a hook in my .bash_login to go into a ssh into a central repository and rsync everything, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution I have seen used by a number of my friends is to put all of their configuration files in a source control repository like [Github](http://www.github.com) which can use your home direcoory as their working directory.

Then all you need to do is pull from the repository and all of your rc files will be up to date. Committing changes from any of your machines and pushing them allows you to make those changes available everywhere.

In order to deal with variation among versions or paths between machines you can either use multiple branches(or tags depending on your choice of revision control) or just use the building in condition abilities of your config files (at those which support such things).

Comment: As an added benefit, your files are versioned. If you want to know what's different between this version and the last one, it's easy to find out.

Comment: I do something similar.  I use CVS for my `$HOME/.*` and `$HOME/bin/*` files.  For various reasons, I don't check them out directly into my home directory; instead, I have `update-home` and `update-bin` scripts that copy files from my checked-out CVS repository.  (I like git, but CVS makes it easier to track versions of individual, and possibly unrelated, files.)

Comment: Yeah, I switched to having my dotfiles in github, and it's super great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put your config files in your Dropbox folder, and symlink to them in your homedir.

Comment: I don't think this will work if I'm remoting into a server and all I have is terminal access